# Getting "an object reference is required to access non-static member" in layout inflater

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, compiler-errors, layout-inflater

I am inflating a layout that contains an imageButton. I am trying to assign an event to the imageButton so that whenever it is clicked, it do the job.
**Below are my code (in c#):**

```
public class HomeScreenAdapter : BaseAdapter<TableItem>
    {
        List<TableItem> items;
        Activity context;
        public HomeScreenAdapter(Activity context, List<TableItem> items)
            : base()
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
        }
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override TableItem this[int position]
        {
            get { return items[position]; }
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var item = items[position];
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ticket_news, null);    view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Image).SetImageBitmap(item.imageBitmap);
            view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imageButton2).Click += delegate
            {
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
                sharingIntent.SetType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "Message");
                StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via")); // here where I am getting the error
                PackageManager pm = PackageManager; // and here I am getting the same error again
            };
            return view;
        }
    }
```

> An object reference is required to access non-static field 'ContextWrapper.SartActivity(Intent)'

Why am I getting this error and how to solve it ?
Thank you

Comment: Try to use context reference to start new activity like context.StartActivity(....);

Comment: Thank you, it worked! If I want to initialise package manager like that: `PackageManager pm = PackageManager;` I am getting the same error as for `StartActivity`. How this one can be solved ?

Comment: Can you please share that code here so i will check and let you know but you need to accept ans as i suggest via comment so it can help other you solve same problem.

Comment: I have edited my code. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like you required **Context** reference to start activity from Adapter class and you already have content reference so just use it as below :

```
context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

Also you can getting PackageManager instance using context :

```
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
```

Comment: What is problem there it's given null instance ?

Comment: I am having some problems with `context.StartActivity`. The `createchooser` is launching many times. Let's say I clicked the imagebutton and the createchooser has launched and I have chosen Whatsapp, the I press back and the createchhoser re-lauch automatically without clicking the imagebutton again. How to solve this ?